# How can I use autolayout on a view which layouts its subviews manually

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a third party widget which I want to autolayout in my controller view. While I found that the widget manually layout its subviews in its `initWithFrame:` method.

I could only make the frame of the widget as I expect, but the frames of subviews on it are **ZERO**.

How can I mix those together. I can't modify the widget. And I can do nothing in my `didLayoutSubivews`, and calling `[self setNeedLayout]` `[self layoutIfNeeded]` before I create the widget instance, because it layouts its subviews immediately when initializing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you say you can do nothing in `didLayoutSubviews`. If the widget only sets up its views in `initWithFrame` and never recalculates their dimensions, it seems that's the *only* place you can do something. Two options I can see are:

1) You need to manually force the widget to re-initialise once your view constraints have been satisfied. Not the best really.

```
- (void)didLayoutSubviews {
     [super didLayoutSubviews];

    self.myWidget = [self.myWidget initWithFrame: self.myWidgetContainer.frame];
}
```

2) Only initialise the widget once your views are set up.

```
- (void)didLayoutSubviews {
    [super didLayoutSubviews];

    if (!self.myWidget) {    
        self.myWidget = [self.myWidget initWithFrame: self.myWidgetContainer.frame];
        [self.myWidgetContainer addSubview:self.myWidget];
    }
}
```

Comment: Umm, seems it's the only solution. I think it will work after I modify my code. Thanks for your answer.